# d3 adding circles on the highest and lowest value on line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know when you want to add circles (dots) on a line chart that this is the way to go

```
pathContainers.selectAll('circle')
.data(function (d) { return d; })
.enter().append('circle')
.attr('cx', function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
.attr('cy', function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
.attr('r', 3);
```

But i would like to put circles only on the highest and lowest point. How can i accomplisch that?

here i found a JSBIN of a d3 chart with the above code inside, perhaps this is a good example to work with

[JSBIN LINE CHART](http://jsbin.com/fagayexuna/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the radius to :

```
.attr('r', function (d) { 
  return d.y == yExtents[0] || d.y == yExtents[1] ? 3 : 0;;
})
```

Like that, only the highest points and lowest will have a circle with a visible radius, the other points will have a circle of radius of 0

See http://jsbin.com/forezavuhu/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of things d3.js provides the very convenient [selection.filter(selector)](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) function that allows to

> apply operators to a subset of elements.

As `selector` you can also pass a `function` with which you're able to determine the min and max data values.

Comment: Great info, could be also an option!

Comment: Thanks. Imho produces a cleaner result in the SVG DOM because you would not end up with these pseudo circles suggested by the other answer. But it's a viable option as well, of course.